# how to let scala's Future running on the current thread?

Tags: scala, future

I'm use `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` to all of Future's executor. But sometime, I do a simple things and just want it not change thread (not put it to thread pool), make it continue running under current thread. Use twitter `Future` where has a `Future.value` to achieve this. How to do in scala's future?

Comment: If you do simple things you don't need a future at all.

Comment: @EndeNeu, the simple thing is just a branch of the works. I must construct a future to ensure final result is `Future`.

Comment: You can do `Future.successful` or `Future.failed` to get a Future that is already "done".

Comment: @LoranceChen ok then it makes sense, the question was a bit misleading, as suggested you should use `Future.successful`.

Comment: @EndeNeu Thanks a lot. : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
Future.fromTry(Try { ... })
```

It doesn't require `ExecutionContext` and basically just evaluates expression immediately and wraps result in future.

Actually, here is it's implementation:

```
def fromTry[T](result: Try[T]): Future[T] = Promise.fromTry(result).future
```

So this seems to be direct analogue of Twitter's `Future.value`.

Also consider using `Future.successful` if your code doesn't trow any exceptions or `Future.failed` if you want to create already failed future.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent of twitter's `Future.value` in scala standard library is `Future.successful`.

`Future.const` is `Future.fromTry`

`Future.exception` is `Future.failed`